# Change role of all users with email address from specific domain upon custom WordPress plugin activation

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'd like to change the role of all users with a specific domain name (@example.com) to a custom role when my plugin is activated.

I found some code for doing it when a user registers and attempted to adapt it to my needs but it doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens when I activate the plugin. The roles don't change and I don't get any errors popping up so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm still learning PHP so please forgive me if this doesn't make sense.

Here's my code:

```
function set_role_by_email( $user_id ){
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
$domain = substr(
    strrchr(
        $user->data->user_email, 
        "@"
    ), 1
); //Get Domain

$custom_role_domains = array( 'example.com' );
if( in_array( $domain, $custom_role_domains ) ){
        foreach( $user->roles as $role )
            $user->remove_role( $role ); //Remove existing Roles
        $user->add_role( 'custom_role' ); //Add role to user
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'set_role_by_email' );
```

Comment: First thing to check is: Is this hook actually running? Put some echo in it and see if it prints out upon registration. `__FILE__` should point to [the main plugin file as pointed out here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)

Comment: Good idea! I added the echo and it gets picked up so at least I know the hook is running now. Still can't seem to get it to work properly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code and see if it works:

```
function set_role_by_email()
{
    $users = get_users();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if (strpos($user->user_email, '@example.com')) {
            foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
                 $user->remove_role($role);
            }
             $user->add_role('custom_role');
        }
    }
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'set_role_by_email');
```

Make sure this code is placed in the main plugin file.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!!